# How to move a onDraw shape by click direction button

Tags: java, android, onclick, onclicklistener

I'm doing a simulator on Android to simulate the move of our robot(represented by a circle in this case). The circle should move forward, turn right or turn left accordingly when the forward/ right/ left button is clicked.
But when I run this program and click the buttons, the circle didn't move...

In the main activity I have the onClickListener like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    findViewById(R.id.forward_button).setOnClickListener(mGlobal_OnClickListener);
    findViewById(R.id.right_button).setOnClickListener(mGlobal_OnClickListener);
    findViewById(R.id.left_button).setOnClickListener(mGlobal_OnClickListener);


}


 View.OnClickListener mGlobal_OnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        GameView gameView = new GameView(Menu.this);
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.forward_button:
                gameView.controlRobot(GameView.FORWARD);
                break;
            case R.id.right_button:
                gameView.controlRobot(GameView.RIGHT);
                break;
            case R.id.left_button:
                gameView.controlRobot(GameView.LEFT);


        }
    }
};
```

In the GamaView Class which extends View class, I draw a circle like this:

```
canvas.drawCircle((currentX * cellHeight)+(cellHeight/2),   //x of center
            (currentY * cellHeight)+(cellHeight/2),  //y of center
            (cellHeight*3*0.45f),                           //radius
            robot);
```

Also In the GameView Class I have this controlRobot method to move this circle:
(The move/ rotate methods are correct. I have tested them)

```
public boolean controlRobot(int keyCode) {
    boolean moved = false;
    boolean rotated = false;

    //move(0):move up on the map
    //move(3):move right on the map
    //move(6):move down on the map
    //move(9):move left on the map

        //forward
    switch (keyCode) {
        case FORWARD:
            if(rotate_count%12==0)
                moved = maze.move(0);

            if(rotate_count%12==3)
                moved = maze.move(3);
            if(rotate_count%12==6)
                moved = maze.move(6);
            if(rotate_count%12==9)
                moved = maze.move(9);
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            rotated = maze.rotate(Maze.RIGHT,rotate_count);
            if(rotated)
            rotate_count+=3;
            break;
        case LEFT:
            rotated = maze.rotate(Maze.LEFT,rotate_count);
            if(rotated)
            rotate_count-=3;
            break;
    }


    if(moved||rotated) {
        //the ball was moved so we'll redraw the view
        invalidate();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: are you putting the GameView in a layout file because the GameView that you are using in your onClick method is a brand new GameView

Comment: @JRowan I put the GameView in a layout file. And the GameView can show on the UI. But the controlRobot method didn't work.

Comment: i put up an answer, when you setContentView() you are using the GameView from your layout, in your onClick method you arent referencing the GameView from the layout

Answer (score 0):

when your reference the GameView in your onclick like this

```
GameView gameView = new GameView(Menu.this);
```

that is not the GameView in your layout file

```
R.layout.main
```

try referencing the GameView in your onClick like you did your buttons

```
findViewById(R.id.forward_button)
```

except with the R.id for the GameView in your layout file